# How can i restrict page loading on reload option (browser)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

i have a jsp page and i want to prevent it from reloading, if a user click on refresh then a dialogue box must be shown and ask for Confirm/Stay here. if user click on confirm the form must be submitted otherwise the page shouldn't refresh.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
            var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
            if (evt) {
                 document.forms["myForm"].submit();
           }
            else {

            }
            return message;
        }
</script>
<form action="SubmitExam.jsp" method="post" id="myForm"> My Code</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean that if users reload the page (press F5 or Ctrl+R) the form will be submitted and the page still stays?

Comment: i have prevent (F5 or Ctrl+R) but i am unable to disable browser refresh button so whenever user click on reload then it just shown a confirm message and it must contains Yes/No.. if user press yes then the form/page must be submit by { document.forms["myForm"].submit(); } and on click of No it stayed on same page.

Comment: Most of your request makes sense except "if user press yes then the form/page must be submit". You *can* add a message to a browser-owned dialog that shows when someone tries to leave a page, but ultimately if they pick the option in that dialog to leave, it will happen instantly, without any of your code running, and you can't prevent it. If something important happened on this page that you don't want to lose, you should asynchronously send it to a server every so often.

Answer (score 0):

**what you want to do, is not possible using event, there's no way captures the return of this event, what you can do is try to make the User answer before pressing the button to reload or close tab**

```
function onMouseLeave(e){
        var pageX = e.pageX || e.clientX;
        var pageY = e.pageY || e.clientY;
        if (pageX < 0 || pageY < 0 || pageY < top) {
           if(confirm('exit intension ?')){
              alert('yes');
           }else{
            alert('no');
           }
        }
    }

    var body = document.body;

    body.addEventListener('mouseleave',onMouseLeave);
```

Comment: I will build a code for you, I be back in a few minutes to answer.

Comment: Okay i am waiting for your answer. !

Comment: Man,  look to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
});
```

---

---

---