# How to make part of html un-reloadable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, upload

In more details, I wish to make a background uploader (in HTML, JS and PHP for backend), which will show the progress bar on a ***part of the page***, and the user can continue working on the site.

An example for this is ***Google Drive*** where you can **upload big files**, and the progress is shown on the bottom-right of the page even if you refresh/reload the page or open another page within google drive.

The aim is to make a div object which will stay on the page even if the page is reloaded or it is changed.

Thank you.

Comment: It's called SPA, check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: Google drive frontend is created in javascript. Google sending and getting request from server without reload. You can read about angularJs,React and another usefull javascript libary what helpfull to create javascript page,

Comment: Just now I realized that reloading google drive while uploading interrupts the upload (Reloading Browser). I guess even Single Page Application would not solve this. 
Anyway thank you for your answers, they were really helpful.

Comment: @AveNgeR upload is sending data to server you can't send 10 MB file in one second, when browser reload page it's interrupting all script. You can check when browser will be reload and popout alert to prevent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221161/how-to-pop-up-an-alert-box-when-the-browsers-refresh-button-is-clicked