# How to restrict page loading in angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular controller,In that user refresh the page manually,In that time I want show the alert popup or restrict that refreshing the page.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221161/how-to-pop-up-an-alert-box-when-the-browsers-refresh-button-is-clicked

Comment: I want custom popup,not predefined popup

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for beforeunload event. beforeunload event will be triggered when someone hits a F5 or refreshes the page

```
var windowElement = angular.element($window);
windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
     alert('user is trying to navigate');
})
```