# How to control page refresh in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component which contains a form.

If a user clicks refresh button in browser. Then it displays a modal popup warning the user that he might lose the form data and ask whether he would like to continue or not?

If the user chooses "No" then he does not lose the filled in form data.

The problem that Im facing is the modal dialog opens on refresh but it doesn't stop the page refresh.

Here is my code

```
//App Component

import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
title = 'test-hostlistener';

@HostListener('window:beforeunload') onRefresh() {
 this.dialog.open(DialogAnimationsExampleDialog);
}

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

//DialogAnimationsExampleDialog Component

@Component({
 selector: 'dialog-animations-example-dialog',
 template: `
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Refresh page</h1>
  <div mat-dialog-content>
   If you refresh the page all data would be gone. Continue?
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
   <button mat-button mat-dialog-close cdkFocusInitial color="accent">Yes</button>
   <button mat-button mat-dialog-close color="warn">No</button>      
  </div>
 `,
})
export class DialogAnimationsExampleDialog {
 constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogAnimationsExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pop up an alert box when the browser's refresh button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221161/how-to-pop-up-an-alert-box-when-the-browsers-refresh-button-is-clicked)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38879742/12914833

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code sample:

```
import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) onRefresh(event: Event) {
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

> Custom message on the dialog model is not supported by new browsers
> you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/beforeunload_event).
>
> Version which are not supported include Chrome: v51, Firefox: v44,
> Safari: v9, Edge: Never Supported, Opera: v38

Answer (score -1):

you can just import FormModule in your app.module, it works with Forms,  i hope it helps you with ordinary html