# Emit message to add-on from content script onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, dom-events

I have a content script which times how long a user views a page. To do this, I inject a content script into each page, start a timer and then emit a message back to the add-on when the `onbeforeunload` event is triggered.

The message never seems to get passed to the background script however.

Given that my `main.js` looks like this:

```
var pageMod = require('page-mod'),
    self = require("self");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://*",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('jquery.min.js'),
                      self.data.url('content.js')],
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on('pageView', function(request) {
      console.log("Request received");
    });
  }
});
```

I can send a message to `main.js` using the following code no problem.

```
self.port.emit('pageView', { visitTime: time });
```

I run into a problem when I try to do it as the user leaves the page however. The message is never received when I do it like this:

```
$(window).bind('onbeforeunload', function(e) {
  self.port.emit('pageView', { visitTime: time });
  // This should prevent the user from seeing a dialog.
  return undefined;
});
```

I've tried listening for `beforeunload` too, that doesn't work either. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you binding the `onbeforeunload` after the document ready? Secondly, did you try to attach the event directly?  `window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  self.port.emit('pageView', { visitTime: time });
  // This should prevent the user from seeing a dialog.
  return undefined;
};` In jsfiddle binding the `onbeforeunload` with jQuery does not work, the direct way does work

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did try the direct way (made the question a few days ago) but I'll try again and get back to you. Binding is happening after jQuery ready so that should be ok.

Comment: [try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CD6DV/1/) and put the jquery and javascript in different order. If I put a `onbeforeunload` in jquery I see 100% handling by javascript and no handling by jQuery. If `beforeunload` is used in jQuery I see intermittent behaviour. Therefore I thinkg javascript is the most stable one. Another thing that you may bounce into: Not all code seems to be executed. Try to add `alert("something");` in the code and you will not see it being executed. If you replace the `return undefined` with a string, at least you should see a dialog to confirm leaving the page

Comment: Ok played around with this a little bit more. I can replicate all the behavior you mention there in the fiddle but it just doesn't seem to work like that in a FF add-on. As far as I can tell, the `self.port.emit` function is not being executed in the unload function body, just like calls to `alert()` are not executed.

Comment: Indeed there may be problems executing stuff in the eventhandler. As last effort you can try to put your code into a time-out `setTimeout(function() { <your code> },0);` use 0 or 1 as the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window` object that content scripts access in Firefox browser add-ons is a proxy object and can be a little temperamental. Using `window.addEventListener` will work.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  # Do stuff then return undefined so no dialog pops up.
  return undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The onbeforeUnload event is not [synchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Irreplaceability_of_the_synchronous_use), so the browser garbage collects the page before it is finished. Use a [synchronous AJAX request](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/Beacon/Overview.html):

```
function Data() 
 {
 var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
 client.open("GET", "/request", false); // third paramater indicates sync xhr
 client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
 client.send({ visitTime: time });
 client.onreadystatechange = emitter;
 }

function emitter()
 {
 self.port.emit('pageView', { visitTime: time });
 }
```

or [return a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802930/setting-onbeforeunload-on-body-element-in-chrome-and-ie-using-jquery) as an alternative.