# Jquery: windows.onunload not working in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cross-browser, window.onunload

In Jquery i invoke the method $(window).unload(). it is used for when i closing the browser window i'm return the some values.this function is working fine in I.E. but it is not working in other browsers.

$(window).unload() function is for i.e ?
Anybody can help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it is window.onunload [widthout an S] and it is a core javascript

Comment: What exactly are you returning? onunload should work same everywhere

Comment: @CME64, sorry you are right. i just edited my question.

Comment: here is my code: $(window).unload(function() {
if(event.clientY < 0) {
returnValue=2;
}
});

Comment: what are you trying to do ? and where are you catching that event? and why do you want to assign a value when the user is leaving the page? it will be dropped anyways

Comment: i'm open the modal window, in this window i have two options to close the window one is cancel button and another one is browser close button. if i closing the window by cancel button means whole function is ended, if i closing by browser window means just browser options. in this place only i returning the values.

Comment: I don't get you, can you elaborate on a clear story line?

Comment: @Elayaraja You can try to use (native) `onbeforeunload` instead of `onunload`. Also the implementation of `showModalDialog()` in Chrome is so buggy, that it's rather useless.

Comment: @Teemu i think it is not right solution for me . can show me any example. ?

Comment: @Elayaraja Please check [main window](http://jsfiddle.net/7Rybx/2/) and [dialog](http://jsfiddle.net/fP86T/4/) at jsFiddle. Dialogs don't seem to work in a fiddle, but you can copy codes and try it yourself. Notice, that probably these snippets are not working in Chrome, but work well in IE and FF. Actually it looks like also `onunload` would work as well in both browsers...

Comment: Hmm... one more thing, `onunload` event has no property named `clientY`, it's only mouseevents having that.

Comment: No, it gets null value while i closing the window even in firefox.

Comment: @Elayaraja Yes, in the fiddle it does (also in IE). You need to create a local copy from the snippets, modal dialog is not working in jsFiddle when using this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure?";
 };
</script>
```

or

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Your own message goes here...';
});
```

in chorme there are several blocked method on onbeforeunload like alert..
A chorme example of the debugging console for an alert:

```
Blocked alert('My Window is reloading') during beforeunload.
```

[ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802930/setting-onbeforeunload-on-body-element-in-chrome-and-ie-using-jquery) [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me)