# Show alert message on chrome similar to firefox on window close.Confirmation message "Leave" or "Stay on this page" not required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show an alert message before window close of webpage.The below code is working fine for firefox and IE but it is not showing the alert message on chrome and safari.

```
**window.onbeforeunload=uEvent;
function uEvent()
{
  alert("you are being logged out");
}**
```

For chrome,I tried using 
return "you are being logged out"; in place of alert message but this alert message gives user option to **"Leave this page" or "stay on this page" which i dont want in my case.**
Please help me out so that chrome and safari have also the similar behavior like firefox and IE

Comment: That is browser controlled. Not sure you can modify that behavior in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Youri Arkesteijn`, you can use this code:

```
var dont_confirm_leave = 0; //set dont_confirm_leave to 1 when you want the user to be able to leave withou confirmation
        var leave_message = 'You sure you want to leave?'
        function goodbye(e) 
        {
            if(dont_confirm_leave!==1)
            {
                if(!e) e = window.event;
                //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                e.returnValue = leave_message;
                //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
                if (e.stopPropagation) 
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                //return works for Chrome and Safari
                return leave_message;
            }
        }   
    window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```

you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802930/setting-onbeforeunload-on-body-element-in-chrome-and-ie-using-jquery)... on stackoverflow..
I checked this in `chrome`, `I.E` and `Mozila`...

Comment: I had already tried this solution but instead of alert message it shows up confirmation message, i.e "Leave this page" or "stay on this page" and i dont want confirmation from user...there should be only "OK" button on the alert message after clicking which the user logs out

Comment: Yes...Kiyarash...a different code altogether which suits my criteria