# onbeforeunload navigation using location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My application is MVC5, I want to alert the user when they close the browser tab.
I found this solution [Setting onbeforeunload on body element in Chrome and IE using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802930/setting-onbeforeunload-on-body-element-in-chrome-and-ie-using-jquery), works great except I use location.href in few cases (custom command buttons inside Telerik grid).
Tried the following:

```
 $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
              validNavigation = true;
    });
```

To avoid asking the user if the want to leave the page.
Is there a better way to alert the user before closing the browser tab?

Comment: and why hashchange then? Question seems to be conflicting to me.

Comment: Maybe haschange is not the right way to detect change in page location; could not the right way to override onbeforeunload when I use location.href. The solution used:  $("a").bind("click", function() {
    validNavigation = true;
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

Need some modifications in this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(validNavigation){
    validNavigation = false;
    /* if this click is valid means user action is not close window or reload page then just return; */
    return;
  }

  /* Want to ask user before leaving the page */
  return "Are you sure you want to leave this page bla bla bla?"; // you can make this dynamic, ofcourse...
};


validNavigation = true;
$(document).on('click', '.validNavigation', function(){
  validNavigation = true;
});
```

Now what you need to do is add `validNavigation` class to all links for those you don't want to show `onbeforeunload` message to user;

**UPDATE** As per comment:

```
function gotopage(args){
  /* set validNavigation to true to don't show warning on page load; */
  validNavigation = true;
  window.location.href = [args];
}
```

For which action you don't wants to show the warning to user simply set `validNavigation = true;` and put statement after it may cause location change;

Comment: Thank you, sounds like a good approach; however I could not find how I can add class to this:
 function gotopage(args) {
            window.location.href = [args];
        }

Comment: When you don't want to show this warning to user either add class to `a` OR set `validNavigation = true;` for some action;

Comment: Worked great.  Expect when using lightgallery lightbox.  I had to add 
    $('#lightgallery').bind("click", function () {
        validNavigation = false;
    });.  Thank  you

Comment: @hncl You need to add `validNavigation = true;` not `validNavigation = false;`;