# alternative to onbeforeunload

Tags: php, javascript

I want to update database when user leave the site. I am using php for my site. I am using javascript function onbeforeunload and call php through ajax to update database.

Now the problem is that the function onbeforeunload is not supported by Opera and Safari, and so the entry should be deleted from database is still over their and affect my database and site.

Any idea or suggestion what i can do?

Comment: You can't see `onbeforeunload` in the list provided by [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)
Why you should use that event? What is the requirement to make it unsuitable to use `onunload` event which is in the list?

Comment: Saeed, if i use onunload than i cant call php through ajax to update my database.

Comment: "You can't see onbeforeunload in the list provided by W3Schools Why you should use that event?" Is W3S your dad or something? There are plenty of legitimate user interactions that only onbeforeunload can perform. Gmail and facebook both use it.. whether it's in W3S' rolodex means little.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is now supported in Opera 15 based on Webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnBeforeUnload` is supported in Safari - what is not supported is the use of AJAX ... you need to use a Synchronous call - you can use `alert` to verify this.....

Comment: @xtremehunger - what would you like to know ?

Answer (score 4):

`onbeforeunload` seems to be a proprietary function from Microsoft. Firefox implemented it while Safari and Opera didn't.
http://www.designerstalk.com/forums/help-me/46310-onbeforeunload-safari-issues.html

Try the `window.onunload` event instead.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload

Example:

```
function unloadPage() {
   alert("unload event detected!");
}
window.onunload = unloadPage;
```

Comment: Thanks, i know alert gonna pop up but this not gonna run my ajax.

Answer (score 1):

`onbeforeunload` should work in Safari. See [Can I pop up a confirmation dialog when the user is closing the window in Safari/Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803887/can-i-pop-up-a-confirmation-dialog-when-the-user-is-closing-the-window-in-safari) (I just tested in Google Chrome and it works)

Comment: yes i know about it, on safari you just able to pop up an alert but not able to run an ajax

Answer (score 0):

[Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) (experimental technology) seems suitable for this kind of tasks.