# pageshow event on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, bfcache

I have the following simple JavaScript, which I require in order to re-initialise some variables on page reload, specifically when the page is served from the Safari BFCache:

```
jQuery(window).bind('pageshow', function(event) {
    // I could inspect event.originalEvent.persisted here to check for BFCache hits,
    // but it isn't required in this instance.

    // Do some initialisation here
});
```

Let's say the user follows the below path, navigating to pages B and C, browsing back (i.e. using the back button) to page A after each:

A -> B -> A -> C -> A

The `pageshow` handler only fires for the first and second visits to A, i.e. the initial page load and the first BFCache load. So in essence, it seems pages served from the BFCache fire `pageshow` once and only once.

Is this the expected behaviour on Safari, and is there a way around it?

Comment: I don't understand why you use `pageshow`. Could you use `$(function()){}`

Comment: or `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: there seems to be an open bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156356 didn't find the workaround yet...

Comment: @GeorgiiIvankin did you find a workaround yet? Seems to be a bug on safari 10 (and recent IOS)

Comment: @ErikBaan no, I didn't, unfortunately.

Comment: There is a bug in Safari as documented here:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156356
The Safari "pageshow" / "pagehide" events don't get fired more than once IF an iFrame is present on the page. In my case it's the Facebook "Like button" iFrame.
Pretty annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appeared to have solved the issue by instead binding to the `popstate` event:

```
jQuery(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
    // Do some initialisation here
});
```

which fires whenever the active history entry changes. This appears to fire consistently rather than just once, so achieves the goal of performing re-initialisation whenever a user lands on page, regardless of the mechanism for getting there.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Safari 10. Popstate event simply never fires.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the `BFCache`, you could add an `onunload=""` attribute on your html body.

```
<body onunload=""></body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a solution to this problem: $(document).ready() is only fired on initial DOM load; if the page is served from the BFCache, it does not fire.

Comment: Could you add an `onunload=""` attribute on your html body?

Comment: The `unload` handler apparently [doesn't necessarily fire in WebKit browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6843651/301894), and I have found this experimentally also.