# Check a web form is closed / refreshed in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function to fire when page/browser close like this:

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

    var y = window.event.clientY;// e.pageY || e.clientY;

    if (y < 0) {

        alert('Window closed');

    }
    else {
        alert('Window refreshed');

    }
```

The function work fine IE but not in other browsers. I want to fire this function only at browser/tab close of a webpage. Not in the page refresh/reload.

Please help.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255649/window-onbeforeunload-not-working

Comment: you have to return string, not use alert(): return  'Window closed';

Comment: I need to know if it is a form close or refresh. how to check this in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function work fine IE but not in other browsers.

That's absolutely normal. Other browsers simply do not allow you to be alerting in this function.

Check that fiddle out in Chrome:

[image]

Sorry, you should forget about alerting in an `onbeforeunload` handler. The only thing you should be doing in this handler is returning a string result:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var y = window.event.clientY;// e.pageY || e.clientY;
    if (y < 0) {
        return 'Window closed';
    }
    else {
        return 'Window refreshed';
    }
};
```

It's the responsibility of the browser to decide how to display this information to the user, not you by telling it to explicitly alert.

Comment: Actually I want o execute an ajax call in while closing the form/browser. Should it work in this scenario?

Comment: That's not guaranteed. If the user clicks on the Close button very quickly the browser will simply redirect away from the page stopping all javascript execution and if your AJAX request didn't make it to the server, well, it might never make it. I wouldn't rely on such behavior.