# JavaScript synchronous or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, browser

I am using Javascript with the `window.onload` and `window.onbeforeunload` functions.

In the `onbeforeunload` I want to run a code that removes an element from an existing list by iterating through the list via a method, but the method doesn't get executed.

When I use the same method in `onload`, everything works fine.

I think the code doesn't get executed in the `onbeforeunload` because the browser is already closed by then and that causes that the method doesn't get executed.

I think I need to do something Sychronous, do you guys have tips on how I can solve this?

```
// working
window.onload = function()
{
    MethodA();
};

// not working
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    MethodA();
};
```

Comment: What is the point of removing an item from the page right before the page closes?  Please include the code for `MethodA()` if you want further help.

Comment: Only way is to return something from `onbeforeunload`. Then the browser will alert the user and wait.

Comment: You need a return value in your `onbeforeunload` handler. See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255649/window-onbeforeunload-not-working)

Comment: @JohnRooney Lol... Return null did the trick! Wow! Thanks!

Comment: Please read about the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) event

Comment: @JohnRooney post it as a answer if you want, so I can accept it.