# jQuery beforeunload reliability

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io, onbeforeunload

I'm a bit confused, why this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
socket.emit('foo')
}
```

does nothing,
while this

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
socket.emit('foo');
});
```

Makes the job done on `chrome 42.0.2311.90 m`
What is the difference?

And how reliable `jQuery` version is?
I want to use `onbeforeunload` to distinguish `disconnect` event while user leaves the app from `disconnect` event while something terribly failed in socket connection on the server or user side.

Comment: For the javascript version you need a `return`, as laid out in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255649/window-onbeforeunload-not-working).

Comment: @BrettDeWoody ah good to know, thx, what about their reliability? Did JQuery  just wraps `window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload',...)` and therefore they are identical?

Comment: FYI, you cannot rely on the `beforeunload` always getting called.  While it may normally be called, there can be some circumstances where it does not get called (power shutdown, laptop/tablet goes to sleep, browser process crashes, etc...).  So, you do have to know how your server is going to behave if it does not get called and have some sort of backstop design for that.

Comment: Yep, it seems that i searched poorly, that questions is realy answers mine.