# How to detect refresh page and redirect to another page

Tags: angular

I want to detect when page is refresh, for example the user press F5:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload') goToPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['../../login']);
}
```

I try something like this but event is not trigger and goToPage() is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is correct, but you can't stop browser refresh the page after router navigate to another page

I create a sample for you, hope it can help you.

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-detect-refresh-page-and-redirect-to-another-page)

**more references**

- [window.onbeforeunload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256224/7291379)