# I can't trigger the unload event in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code runs fine on Firefox, **but I can't make the unload event work on Chrome** anymore. Did Chrome stop supporting the unload event?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageHidden(evt) { alert("Are you sure 1?"); } //WORKS ON FIREFOX BUT NOT IN CHROME
    window.addEventListener("pagehide", pageHidden, false);

    window.onunload = function () { alert("Are you sure 2?"); } //TRIGGERS ON LOAD NOT ON UNLOAD

    $(window).unload(function () { //WORKS ON FIREFOX BUT NOT IN CHROME
        alert("Are you sure 3?");
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
TEST WEBSITE
<a href="http://www.iamawesome.com">external link</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

How can I get the unload event to work in Chrome?

Thanks!

---

**ANSWER:
Don't test the unload event with alerts ;)**

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803887/can-i-pop-up-a-confirmation-dialog-when-the-user-is-closing-the-window-in-safari

Comment: you're not triggering anything anywhere in your code. you're just binding handlers.

Comment: Check [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10509). In short, it won't work in Chrome; try to use `.onunload` handler instead, but even that might be 'fixed' as well. )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
window.onunload = alert("Are you sure 2?");
```

This is incorrect.  You are setting `onunload` to the result of `alert`, you need to set it to a function:

```
window.onunload = function(){
    alert("Are you sure?");
}
```

If you want to use jQuery, this will work in all browsers.

```
$(window).unload(function () {
     alert("Are you sure?");
});
```

**NOTE**: It might *seem* like it's not working in Chrome, but it is.  That's because Chrome blocks `alert`s in the `onunload` event.

Comment: That was the issue. Chrome was blocking all my alerts. I tried a console.log and it works fine. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: If you use alerts, you should see an error in Chrome's console.

Comment: This no longer worked for me, Please see @jeteon solution below, that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    // code
};
```

or

```
window.onpagehide = function () {
    // code
};
```

Comment: Thanks Korikulum! I tried this but it is not displaying the alert message I write inside each function

Comment: onpagehide is a useful event to know about, but you can't trust it to get called every time a page goes away.  For example, if you launch a new tab, and then close the whole browser, the event may not fire.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read it seems Chrome blocks alerts once that event has been triggered. You can run some functions, however, just not anything that interacts with the user it seems.

From [window.onbeforeunload in Chrome: what is the most recent fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626059/window-onbeforeunload-in-chrome-what-is-the-most-recent-fix), it seems, if all you want to do is pop up a confirmation message, you have to do it by returning a string with the message from the function you set as the callback.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // Some wrap up code (no alerts, confirms, redirects, etc)
    return 'My confirmation messsage'; 
}
```

The text "My confirmation message" will then show up in a confirmation dialogue of Chrome's choosing. Firefox documents this behaviour [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload).

Comment: Thank you this worked for me and meshed well with my current design

Answer (score 0):

You don't trigger anything - you just execute the expression which you want to add as a handler:

```
window.onunload = function(event) {
    alert("Are you sure 2?");
};
```

Comment: Still not working, I can exit the page and the alert message won't show up :(