# Close Wordpress modal popup on browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog

I'm using the plugin Popups for Divi on a Wordpress website.

I want to close the modal on click of browser back button (I need that especially for mobiles). 
I tried using the Js code below, but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var openModalHashStateId = "#modalOpen";
  $('#myPopup').on('DiviPopup.show', function(event) {
  window.location.hash = openModalHashStateId;
  });
  $('#myPopup').on('DiviPopup.hide', function(event) {
  window.history.back();
  });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377383/close-pop-up-on-back-button

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap modal.