# Closing a related modal when the user clicks the browser's back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, popstate

I have a simple project in which I've included a modal component that can be closed by the browser's back button. When a modal is opened, a hash appears in the URL. If the user clicks the back button, the modal is closed and the hash disappears. However, when I try to open a modal within another modal, a serious problem arises. Pressing the back button closes both modals, as the popstate callback function runs for both. I'm really stuck on this issue.

this is my index file

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import {Inter} from 'next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
import {useState} from "react";
import Modal from "@/components/Modal";

const inter = Inter({subsets: ['latin']})

export default function Home() {
    const [showModal1, setShowModal1] = useState(false);
    const [showModal2, setShowModal2] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app"/>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
            </Head>
            <main className={styles.main}>
                <button onClick={() => setShowModal1(true)}>Click to open modal1</button>
                <Modal hash={'#modal1'} isOpen={showModal1} onClose={() => setShowModal1(false)}>
                    This Content is used for Modal1
                    <button onClick={() => setShowModal2(true)}>
                        Click to open modal2
                    </button>
                </Modal>
                <Modal hash={'#modal2'} isOpen={showModal2} onClose={() => setShowModal2(false)}>
                    This Content is used for Modal2
                </Modal>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

and this is my modal component

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

const Modal = ({isOpen, children, onClose, hash}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOpen) {
router.push(hash);
            window.addEventListener('popstate', onClose);
            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('popstate', onClose);
            }
        }
    }, [isOpen]);

    return (
        isOpen && <div style={{
            background: 'white',
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0',
            width: '100vw',
            height: '100vh',
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            gap: '10px',
            padding: '20px'
        }}>
                <span
                    onClick={() => {
                        onClose();
                        if (router.asPath.includes(hash)) {
                            router.back();
                        }
                    }}
                    style={{
                        background: 'coral',
                        borderRadius: '10px',
                        alignSelf: 'center'
                    }}>Close Modal</span>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

thank you in advanced for any affort

Comment: Changes to hashes can be captured with the ['hashchange'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) event. Give it a try.

Comment: didn't work. do you have any other solutions

Comment: i dont fully remeber but it had something to do with `closeOnNavigation: false` that all dialogs closed at navigation

Comment: @wutzebaer I think it is for angular

Comment: @AliEhyaie closeOnNavigation is from angular: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api