# Remove/Clear local storage when all tabs are closed

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage

I have to clear local storage when my website is closed from all the tabs or browser windows is closed by clicking close button or any short cut key, I have Google for it since 2-3 days, but not getting any success. Do you have any way to achieve this?

Comment: clear the storage during the "unload" event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onunload` event in your `body` tag to trigger local storage clearing:

`<body onunload = "javascript:window.localStorage.clear()">`

There is one caveat, however, the `onunload` event is supported in IE, Firefox, and Safari, but **not** supported properly in Chrome or Opera yet.

Comment: where do you have the information, that chrome does not support the `unload` event?

Comment: Read carefully - "properly", means that older versions of Chrome have problems with it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182559/i-cant-trigger-the-unload-event-in-chrome, and also https://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/

Comment: hi @bodi0 and christoph, but If user press ctrl+f5 or refresh button, I want local storage remain same, If 2 tabs has my websites open, and some close just one tab, then also local storage remain, when all tabs are closed from browser, then only I have to remove local storage.

Comment: You will have to combine this with cross tab messaging: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1100416/1816580

Comment: @ArtjomB. no need for complicated messaging, sessionStorage will do fine.

Comment: @bodi0 That's not what the word "properly" means.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `localStorage`, you have to use the lesser known little brother `sessionStorage`. It does exactly what you want - store the data until the end of the session.

[Check out this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uE4Pc/1/). Reload it a couple of times to see the counter increment. After closing the window, the counter will get reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
sessionStorage : if you want to handle in another tabs. 
localStorage : just in current tabs.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
       window.localStorage.clear();
       window.sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: clearing the sessionStorage in the unload Event will break the functionality, as a normal refresh also triggers this event.

Comment: It will be the same with onbeforeunload event? 
Thanks for your informations about the break of "unload" . Very useful.

Answer (score -4):

```
window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not helpful. Here you must *at least* explain under what circumstances this code should be invoked. Moreover, the code you have does not actually *clear* the storage: it removes only one key from the storage. I'll add before you start editing this that if you edit it in such a way that it presents a solution that has already been presented, the you should just delete it. Duplicate solutions are not welcome.