# Clear tokens in Local Storage when all tabs or Browser is closed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, local-storage

I want to remove the user Authentication when the application has been loaded in multiple tabs. Once all the tabs that had the application loaded are closed or the entire browser is closed, I want to remove the token stored in local storage. When a user again opens a new tab and tries to enter the application, it should redirect to the login page. How can this be achieved in react, like how to detect that all tabs that have that application loaded closed?

**Note --** I want to remove the token and display the login page only when all the tabs are closed or the browser is closed.

**For an Instance**,
If the application has been loaded in 5 tabs, on the closing of all 5 tabs only I need to remove the token.

Is it possible to use a Broadcast channel to achieve this? but I am not sure how to implement them

Comment: Maybe you need to use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That would be my suggestion as well, but sessionStorage isn't shared between multiple tabs of the same page, so it probably wont be enough for this particular use case.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Yes bud, that's why I need to use local storage, is there any possible way to implement this?

Comment: Hope this one helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759555/remove-clear-local-storage-when-all-tabs-are-closed

Comment: @mchowdam, appreciate for sharing it, but the problem is in most cases they have provided for a single tab closing, but my need is when multiple tabs that have the application loaded are getting close

Comment: I have a workaround but not a good solution, we can explore more. We have a cookie/local storage variable which indicates that a tab is opened, all tabs set this variable by `setInterval` of very short duration, whenever a tab is closed or App is unmounted we can reset this variable, and `clearInterval` after clearing it if it is set again then another tab is opened so don't logout else if the variable is not set after clearing then this is the last tab setting it so the user can be logged out.

Comment: @ShivamSharma, could you please elaborate more, sorry I am a newbie to javascript., so I can understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this way?

1. Count every tab open and save it to localStorage
2. Handle event unload and update localStorage if `openedTab === 0` then clear it in unload event

Comment: The idea seems straightforward and logical. I implemented it once and tackled a few days with it. At the end, it made me frustrated and I found out it does not work in practice.